# Iterate array of objects in Liquid language

Tags: for-loop, liquid

I'm new to Liquid Language. I have a use case where I want to loop through the array of objects and print some values.

Might me my syntax is incorrect.

I have an array of objects like below. I'm getting this data from rest api
I have pasted here some part of it.

```
assign htd_product_ids = 
     [
        {
            "id": 113608,
            "car_name": "Maruti Suzuki Alto K10 VXi",
            "mileage": 13479,
            "make_year": 2018,
            "final_price": 345000,
            "fuel_type": "petrol",
            "full_url": "http://www.spinny.com/buy-used-cars/hyderabad/maruti-suzuki/alto-k10/vxi-kondapur-2018/113608/"
        },
        {
            "id": 113011,
            "car_name": "Maruti Suzuki Celerio VXi AMT",
            "mileage": 25257,
            "make_year": 2016,
            "final_price": 413000,
            "fuel_type": "petrol",
            "full_url": "http://www.spinny.com/buy-used-cars/hyderabad/maruti-suzuki/celerio/vxi-amt-kondapur-2016/113011/"
        },
        {
            "id": 112609,
            "car_name": "Maruti Suzuki Swift Dzire ZXI",
            "mileage": 54600,
            "make_year": 2015,
            "final_price": 541000,
            "fuel_type": "petrol",
            "full_url": "http://www.spinny.com/buy-used-cars/hyderabad/maruti-suzuki/swift-dzire/zxi-kondapur-2015/112609/"
        }
     ]
```

I want to loop through this array and print car_name

```
{% for product in htd_product_ids %}
  {{forloop.index}}. {{product.car_name}}
{% endfor %}
```

***forloop.index*** is working fine but ***product.car_name*** is not printing the car name.

Please correct me if there is any syntax error or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign json to a variable. It's a known issue with liquid.

Using a liquid sandbox to test (https://masterdatapoc.z6.web.core.windows.net/), the loop you're using is correct, though the json may be wrong:

Source Json:

```
{"htd_product_ids":  [
        {
            "id": 113608,
            "car_name": "Maruti Suzuki Alto K10 VXi",
            "mileage": 13479,
            "make_year": 2018,
            "final_price": 345000,
            "fuel_type": "petrol",
            "full_url": "http://www.spinny.com/buy-used-cars/hyderabad/maruti-suzuki/alto-k10/vxi-kondapur-2018/113608/"
        },
        {
            "id": 113011,
            "car_name": "Maruti Suzuki Celerio VXi AMT",
            "mileage": 25257,
            "make_year": 2016,
            "final_price": 413000,
            "fuel_type": "petrol",
            "full_url": "http://www.spinny.com/buy-used-cars/hyderabad/maruti-suzuki/celerio/vxi-amt-kondapur-2016/113011/"
        },
        {
            "id": 112609,
            "car_name": "Maruti Suzuki Swift Dzire ZXI",
            "mileage": 54600,
            "make_year": 2015,
            "final_price": 541000,
            "fuel_type": "petrol",
            "full_url": "http://www.spinny.com/buy-used-cars/hyderabad/maruti-suzuki/swift-dzire/zxi-kondapur-2015/112609/"
        }
     ]}
```

Template:

```
{% for product in htd_product_ids %}
  {{forloop.index}}. {{product.car_name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Output:

```
1. Maruti Suzuki Alto K10 VXi

2. Maruti Suzuki Celerio VXi AMT

3. Maruti Suzuki Swift Dzire ZXI
```